Sending data in a MUI component AutoComplete
I have a component that needs to display names in the options list, but at the same time send the name ID in the form. How can this be done?
const employees: UserModel[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Hugo',
    lastName: 'Race'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Sheppard'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Kate',
    lastName: 'Ostin'
  },
];

<Box
  component="form"
  id="applicationForm"
  noValidate
>
  <Autocomplete
    options={employees}
    getOptionLabel={(option: UserModel) => (`${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`)}
    getOptionKey={(option: UserModel) => option.id}
    id="studentId"
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
    renderInput={(params) =>
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Сотрудник"
        variant="filled"
        error={errors.studentId ? true : false}
        {...register('studentId', {
          required: errorLocales.validation.requiredField,
        })}
      />}
  />
</Box>

Now when sending a form the full name is sent, but you need to send the ID

try to render the Option instead of the TextField, I think it should works

You can obtain the result by following this

renderOption - we can manupilate our object data in here. You can use tags inside it. option prop is responsible for handling your object data.
onChange - There is a prop salled details that responsible for handling your selected object. In there you can capture you id, firstName, and lastName.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState({
    id: 0,
    fullName: '',
  });

  const employees = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'Hugo',
      lastName: 'Race'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'Jack',
      lastName: 'Sheppard'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstName: 'Kate',
      lastName: 'Ostin'
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={employees}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      value={employee.fullName}
      renderOption={(props, option, state) => {
        return (
          <div {...props}>
            <p>{option.firstName} {option.lastName}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Employee" />}
      onChange={(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any, reason: string, details: any) => {
        setEmployee({
          ...employee,
          id: details?.option.id,
          fullName: `${details?.option.firstName} ${details?.option.lastName}`,
        });
      }}
    />
  );
}


Unfortunately your solution didn't work
there should be a name in the input and in the selection list, and only the ID should be sent through the form

You can simply send employee.id

Or maintain different state for handling id

The autocomplete component in MUI does not support the name attribute. You can do the following to achieve your goal.
    const employees: UserModel[] = [
      {
            id: 1,
            firstName: 'Hugo',
            lastName: 'Race'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            firstName: 'Jack',
            lastName: 'Sheppard'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            firstName: 'Kate',
            lastName: 'Ostin'
          },
        ];
    const [state, setState] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (event, value) => {
      setState({ studentId: value.id });
    };
        
        <Box
          component="form"
          id="applicationForm"
          noValidate
        >
          <Autocomplete
            options={employees}
            getOptionLabel={(option: UserModel) => (`${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`)}
            getOptionKey={(option: UserModel) => option.id}
            id="studentId"
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
            onChange={handleChange}
            renderInput={(params) =>
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Сотрудник"
                variant="filled"
                error={errors.studentId ? true : false}
                {...register('studentId', {
                  required: errorLocales.validation.requiredField,
                })}
              />}
          />
        </Box>

